# Python: How to print values with carriage return on Terminal

Tags: python

When i run the below script using PyCharm, no newline is printed during the download process.

However when i run this script on Terminal, newlines are printed.

Here are the codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import time
import ssl
import urllib.request


def UrlOpen(url, filename):
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url=url, context=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23))
    size = int(data.headers.get("content-length"))
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        count = 0
        now = time.time()
        for i in data:
            count += len(i)
            f.write(i)
            print("\rSize: {} b, Downloaded: {} b, Completed: {} %, Elapsed: {} s, Speed: {} b/s"
                  .format(size,
                          count,
                          int(100 * count / size),
                          int(time.time() - now),
                          count / (time.time() - now)), flush=True, end="")  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_url = "http://muhendislik.istanbul.edu.tr/insaat/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/temel_in%C5%9Faat%C4%B1.pdf"
    file_path = "/home/tanberk/Masaüstü/test.pdf"
    UrlOpen(test_url, file_path)
```

How can i print a single line when i use this script on Terminal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS and terminal?

Comment: OS: Ubuntu, terminal: bash

Comment: I tried your code on my system, no new lines in terminal (Xubuntu 14.04). Try next `print("\u001b[1000<YOUR TEXT>")`, i.e. `\u001b[1000` escape code in the beginning of string.

Comment: sorry, right sequence is `\u001b[1000D`

Comment: sorry but still it keeps on printing many times. :/

Comment: it's a terminal issue, try another terminal, for example `terminator`, (`sudo apt-get install terminator`).

Comment: strange, it prints newlines too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\r` is an old style Mac line terminator or carriage return. Did you mean `\n` for a newline?

`print` always includes a newline. You have to use `sys.stdout.write` to exclude it, or use the `end=` keyword argument to the function version of print from future.

Comment: Not newline, no newline.

Comment: `sys.stdout.write` still prints newlines and i should look at future module. thanks.